Gospel tag question
So I tried to add a gospel tag, but it was said to be too similar to the 'gospels' tag which seems to be specifically in reference to the first 4 books of the New Testament. Is there a more appropriate tag for the word gospel? Otherwise, is it not the case that the concept of the gospel is distinct enough to separate it from the 'gospels' that technically refer to a specific set of texts?

Use the tag the-gospel for questions about the Gospel itself.

@curiousdannii,  thank you. Just typing away only auto-populates 6 options max such that you can't see 'the-gospel' as a legitimate option. Is there some way to either increase the number of options for this site or to indicate that there are more options that match than are shown?

I'm not sure about that sorry.

It looks like you are referring to this question. I updated the gospels tag with instructions to use the-gospel tag. Both work with drop-down tag lists.

@Jesse, thanks Jesse the problem is if you type gospel in the edit tag form you'll never see the-gospel. You'll see Mathew Mark Luke and John and gnostic-gospels before you'll see the-gospel. Probably due to alphabetical order. Doesn't make a lot of sense. I wonder if we can remove the word gospel from the tag description of Matthew Mark Luke and John or have gospel be an option instead of the-gospel.

I think it's showing the top 6 matching tags according to the number of questions (including matthew, mark, luke, john because of tag synonyms.) So if the-gospel gets three more questions it will overtake gnostic-gospels and be shown in the suggested tags. There's probably three appropriate questions it could be added to, if you wanted to hurry that along.

I made gospel a synonym of the-gospel, and now it's at the front of the suggestion list!

Thanks, @curiousdannii . You da man! ...Please correcte if you are not a man :-)

@curiousdannii THIS is the kind of thing we moderators are here to do. Thanks Austin for bringing this to our attention!
